# CMake generates SHARED library but not STATIC library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to generate a static library using CMAKE and Android Studio(2.3.2). Below is what my CMakeLists.txt looks like. I am unable to generate .a file, however when I change the library to SHARED, CMakeTestModule.so file gets generated when I do "Build->Rebuild Project". Is it required for me to add/set any flag for building STATIC libraries.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project (CMakeTestProject)

include_directories(
    src/main/cpp/
)

add_library(
    CMakeTestModule
    STATIC
    src/main/cpp/CMakeTestModule.cpp
)

add_executable(
    CMakeTestModule_test
    src/main/cpp/CMakeTestModule_test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(CMakeTestModule_test CMakeTestModule)
```

This is what my build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'armeabi'
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be an Android NDK issue, not cmake. Have a look at [BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html)

Comment: There are quite a few results when searching for [`gradle cmake build static library`](https://www.google.com/search?q=gradle+cmake+build+static+library)

Comment: @SteveLorimer  I am using CMake to build my ndk stuff, I am not sure how to use BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY in CMake.

Comment: That flag is correct. Are you sure it is not generating static library? You can turn verbose mode on for Makefile and look at output (In CMake file do `set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON )`).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by specifying the target in the build.gradle. Something like below. Since apk only uses .so files, we need to mention the targets for static libraries and executables.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 8

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            abiFilters 'armeabi'
        }
        targets "CMakeTestModule_test", "CMakeTestModule"
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this did not work for me when i tried building a static library

Comment: @famagusta add targets inside cmake


externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            abiFilters 'armeabi'
           targets "CMakeTestModule_test", "CMakeTestModule"
        }
        
    }